# PDO INSERT & UPDATE query to different tables

Tags: sql, pdo, sql-update

I have a PDO SQL script which enables a user to complete a form which captures band information. It then posts this information to my database table called 'bands'. This works fine.

Simultaneously, I would like the script to update a different table called 'users' which has a column called 'num_bands' which needs to increase by a value of +1 if the user creates more than one band.

I have tried a number of methods, but none of them work. The script seems to be able to INSERT to the 'bands' table perfectly, but I cannot UPDATE the 'users' table. Here is the 'register_band' script:

```
<?php

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("common.php");

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page.
    header("Location: ../index.php");

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it,
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in.
    die("Redirecting to ../index.php");
}

// This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted
// If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username
    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors
        // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form
        // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an
        // exercise for you to implement yourself.
        die("Please enter a username.");
    }

    // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table.
    // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to
    // protect against SQL injection attacks.
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO bands (
                    member_id,
            username,
            bandname,
            bandhometown,
            bandtype

        ) VALUES (
                    :member_id,
            :username,
            :bandname,
            :bandhometown,
            :bandtype  
        )
    ";


    // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not
    // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store
    // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk).
    $query_params = array(
            ':member_id' => $_POST['member_id'],
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':bandname' => $_POST['bandname'],
        ':bandhometown' => $_POST['bandhometown'],
        ':bandtype' => $_POST['bandtype']
    );

    try
    {
        // Execute the query to create the user
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }


    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

$query2 = "UPDATE users 
           SET num_bands = num_bands + 1 
           WHERE id = :member_id";

$stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);

    // This redirects the user to the private page after they register
    header("Location: ../gig_view.php");

    // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit.
    die("Redirecting to ../gig_view.php");
}

?>
```

I'm running this in non-production mode at the moment, so the code is not 100%. How do I get the script to UPDATE the 'users' table?

Comment: Show us your attempts to update the 'users' table.

Comment: I have updated the initial code offering to show my attempt at the UPDATE statement. I am no expert in PDO, so I concede that it may be a poor attempt.

Comment: Just to be sure, you didn't place it between try {} catch() {} as it is the case right here ?

Comment: My mistake, I have updated the code again to show my original placement. Thanks for noticing that :)

Comment: I see a `$db->prepare($query2)` for the `UPDATE users` statement, but no corresponding `$stmt2->execute(array(':member_id' => $_POST['member_id']));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt->closeCursor(); 

$query2 = "UPDATE users 
           SET num_bands = num_bands + 1 
           WHERE id = :member_id";

$stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);

$params = array(':member_id' => $_POST['member_id']);
$result = $stmt2->execute($params);
```

The code you have here is well documented, and explains how to use PDO statements, prepared queries and how to execute them with parameters.

Just follow the same pattern as you did with your SELECT, only the string of the query is meant to change here.

Comment: Closing statements isn't really that important except for `SELECT` if fetching may not be completed. What was important here is the part you _didn't_ mention...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, was editing my answer. I agree about the closeCursor, It's not needed/important here, but I feel like it can help to avoid problems to simply call it everytime. Maybe I'm wrong ?

Comment: It's a harmless habit on `INSERT/UPDATE` statements but has no effect on them. It doesn't deallocate the statement, so `$stmt` is available still to be executed again.

Comment: Gentlemen, I can't thank you enough. This fix has worked perfectly.